# How to SetValue a Dynamic Type Field

Tags: c#, types

string typeName = Request.QueryString["TypeName"];
    Type t = Type.GetType(typeName);
    t.GetField("SomeField").SetValue(?,"Hello");

In the code above, I am creating Type object which holds the information of a Custom Type whose name comes from QueryString.

Now the problem is this Custom Type has SomeField and I want to assign value to this field but I have no idea which Type can come from QueryString so I can't say any specific type at the **?** place in SetValue method.

What should I do ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very likely the wrong way to do something. If you could give a more concrete example of what you're trying to accomplish, we could perhaps give some alternative ways to do it.

That being said, you don't have an instance of TypeName, so you obviously can't have anything to go in the place of the "?". You could use [System.Activator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.aspx) to create a new instance of that TypeName though.

Example:

```
string typeName = Request.QueryString["TypeName"];
Type t = Type.GetType(typeName);
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
t.GetField("SomeField").SetValue(instance, "Hello");
```

Comment: Type can't create an instance or something to accomplish it ?

Comment: System.Activator is what you use to create an instance.

Comment: Thanks, besides that solution, is there any other solution you know and suggest me ?

Comment: Without known what you're using it for?  No.

Comment: Yeap thanks, actually I got it but I was asking blah blah....whatever...Thanks :)

Comment: If you know the set of those type which you'll be allowing through query string then you can use Switch - Case to identify which type is it once you identify the type you can assign its fields. Yes, it doesn't sound neat but it'll certainly server the purpose. If you identified the type name you didn't even need to use type object to create its instance.

Comment: @S M Kamran : I thought that but I just wanted different solutions, and nice one came out from Jimmy.

Thanks S M Kamran.